# linux tool to list all functions in a source file?

Tags: java, c++, c, linux, utilities

I am looking for a command line utility on *nix, that can dump the names of all the functions, classes etc. defined in a file(C/C++/Java)

Comment: What kind of file, what language, do you mean complied elf file?

Comment: What language is the source file in?

Comment: For java  write a reflection based code to do it. Please check if c++filt does some thing useful for you  - http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**ctags**](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) can give you that (and much more). It is included with most Linux distributions...
http://ctags.sourceforge.net/whatis.html

Comment: i know about ctags, but it generates its tags file, which then is needed to be imported to an editor e.g. vim. I was asking for a simple utility, that just prints the function names on console, if ctags does that I am not sure

Comment: then you want `ctags -x`, which prints a human readable summary of stuff.

Comment: Also `ctags -f -` prints the output to stdout, and not a tag file. You can then use `awk` or something similar...

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which language you refer to: if:

- complied elf file then you have readelf utility providing that you compiled file with debug information "-g"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would be useful for your exact purpose, but take a look at [GCC-XML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Doxygen to list all your functions (see also XML output possibility)
http://www.doxygen.nl/

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at [`cscope`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cscope) which is similar to ctags suggested in the accepted answer. It creates its own symbol database. It provides a nice interface for you, enabling search of a given symbol/inclusion/file/declaration within your project.