# Is there any way to get all function names imported from header files included in C++?

Tags: c++, header-files

Is there any way to get all function names (in string) declared in imported header file in C++?

like in python:
`print(dir(--importedModule--))`
This would give a list of all the methods declared in *importedModule* in string.

I have done something like this in Java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.*;

public class random
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            // create class object 
            Class classobj = Math.class; 

            // get list of methods 
            Method[] methods = classobj.getMethods(); 
            Set<String> abc = new HashSet<String>(); 
            // get the name of every method present in the list 
            for (Method method : methods) {   
                abc.add(method.getName());
            } 
            System.out.println(abc);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

    }
}
```

So is there anything like this in C++ ?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your problem? Are you searching for a C++ header parser?

Comment: if this would exist, it wouldnt do what you want, becaue headers can include other headers. The way to get that information is to read the documentation for the header

Comment: @idclev463035818: C++20's modules might help in that regard :)

Comment: There are tools which can read source files and generate references of symbols for them. But from inside the source being currently compiled? Then no it's not possible. There's no "true" [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) in C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801518/linux-tool-to-list-all-functions-in-a-source-file

Comment: @Gupta I am making an autocomplete feature for an editor, where I need to show user the imported header files' functions available to import. I have a compiler backend, from where I can import and send back a list of just method names to the user of available methods.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I get it there can be other header files imported inside that one particular package. But dont want those other method names, just the ones declared in it. As by my use case just need to show user the names of methods in the package, nothing more than that.

Comment: Unless it's just for fun and a bit of learning exercise, then don't try to implement a C++ parser yourself. There are good ones available in library form, like for example Clang. The Clang libraries and tools are already used in editors and IDE's to handle C++ code editing with code completion and syntax highlighting (even commercial ones).

Comment: @JatinVerma: You cannot really ignore other `#include` to only focus on specific header, as `#include` might declare type for current header, or MACRO, which might enable/disable some section or even change meaning.

Comment: Qt's moc can do something like it. [QMetaObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html)